# Which is linked to which?

Tags: conditionals

Sentence:
In a sense, of course, the more open-ended and free narrative approaches that
have been discussed already are intended to avoid these problems, "even if the question remains of whether research subjects can just be enabled to speak or if there is a role for the researcher, *if not speaking for them at least actively drawing out* the implications".

Q:
qoutationed part seems strange in overall, but is understandable exept its italic part. I can't separate its phrases: {if, not ... least, actively ...} or {if not, speaking ... actively, drawing ...} or ...

Comment: I think a comma is needed after "if not speaking for them" and the word "then". So "if not speaking for them, then at least actively drawing out the implications". But as you say, it's strange.

Comment: @WeatherVane
Some other place we see this sentence: They will
already have given up their time to participate in the research, and taking up
more time may not be particularly attractive to them.
Does such a structure really exist in English? I wonder... Most surprising is that the book is a published guidance book for dissertation...